# M.E.R.N Heroku app crashes in production and can only run locally in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, production-environment

My app only works locally when the backend node/express server is running on http://localhost:3000 and the react/client-side server is running on http://localhost:3001. When deployed Heroku only serves my Login page and if I click the login button on that Login page it's supposed to redirect me to the Spotify authorization from the Passport Spotify Oauth Strategy but crashes. If I run both the back end and front end servers the Heroku app will render properly which is an issue because I need the app to work independently from my local machine. I've tried configuring my package.json files to run the build in production but that attempt still fails. I need Heroku to run my servers in production is this possible using Webpack?

Github repo - https://github.com/kimanikelly/The-Aux

Heroku app link - https://the-aux.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Your "Login With Spotify" button links to localhost:3000

Comment: in your client/package.json you still have proxy to localhost:3000

Comment: Yes but in development, that route is used to direct the user to the Spotify authorization page and if successful redirects the user to the home page. Would I have to change my routes or this to work in production?

Comment: @Chiller 
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"

This is how I configured the proxy on the React side but still have the same issues.

Comment: the proxy in production should use the url of heroku

Comment: @Chiller Thanks I was able to configure the routing and replace the routes pointing to localhost:3000/localhost:3001 with https://the-aux.herokuapp.com/auth/spotify and https://the-aux.herokuapp.com/home. I didn't realize until a few hours ago that I cant use those local servers in production. Now that the routing is complete and pages render I have to figure out how to get a new access token on the sign-in so the Spotify web player can function. The player was functional in development because of the local database but using process.env.MONGODB_URI doesn't allow a new token to be created.